# Sinatra caching expires only one part of the HAML file

Tags: ruby, caching, sinatra, haml

I'm using [sinatra-cache](https://github.com/kematzy/sinatra-cache) to my Sinatra application, to display overnights. Works great, the only problem is that it updates only a part of the HAML file. I don't understand why this happens. I'using a cron script to `kill -HUP` unicorn, but I'm trying to figure out why some parts of the HAML get updated while others do not.

Here is the HAML file:

```
-# coding: utf-8

!!!
%html
  %head
    %link{rel: "stylesheet", href: "http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.0r4/build/reset/reset-min.css", type: "text/css"}
    %link{rel: "stylesheet", href: "/css/open.css", type: "text/css"} 
  %body
    #wrapper
      #header
        #content
          - if @ov_name
            - if @list.size > 0
              %h3 Σήμερα #{@mera} #{@date} 
              %h2 ΔΙΑΝΥΚΤΕΡΕΥΕΙ: 
              %h1 #{@ov_name} 
              %h2 #{@ov_address} - #{@ov_no} 
              %h2 Τηλ: #{@ov_phone}
              %hr
              %h4 Εφημερεύουν:
              - @list.each do |id|
                - d = @a.display(id)
                %h4 #{d[:name]}, #{d[:address]} #{d[:no]}, #{d[:phone]}
            - else
              %h3 Σήμερα #{@mera} #{@date} 
              %h2 ΔΙΑΝΥΚΤΕΡΕΥΕΙ: 
              - if @ov_description
                %hr
                %h1 #{@ov_name} 
                %h1 #{@ov_address} #{@ov_no}
                %h2 (#{@ov_description})
                %h1 Τηλ: #{@ov_phone}
              - else
                %hr
                %h1 #{@ov_name} 
                %h1 #{@ov_address} #{@ov_no}
                %h1 Τηλ: #{@ov_phone}
          - else
            %h2 Δεν υπάρχει διανυκτέρευση για την σημερινή ημερομηνία
            %h2 επικοινωνήστε με τον φαρμακοποιό.
        #footer
          %p Συστήματα Ψηφιακής Σήμανσης "Piseli.net"
```

The `@list` variable is not getting updated for some reason. So when the time shifts (after 08:00 AM every day) I get a view where the upper part (overnight pharmacy) gets displayed but the part below `%hr` (overday pharmacies) do not. You can see the app live [here](http://piseli.net/overnights/drama).

Comment: Turn off your caching and run Sinatra in development mode. Simulate a time shift to force the HAML output change. If HAML generates the changed output correctly, then it's working correctly and the problem is outside your code. At that point I think this is a server configuration problem and not for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I can recommend [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) for the tests.